# creating dynamic height UIImageViews programmatically in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, nsurlconnection, lazy-loading

I want to load `UIImage` dynamically. and those are in different sizes. What I tried to do it reset my `UIImageView` frame after downloaded the image.

```
 let imgVw:UIImageView! = UIImageView.init(frame: CGRectMake(5, self.otherVidY, imgvwWidth, scrollH-10))
        imgVw.image=UIImage(named: "NotFound")
        self.scroll.addSubview(imgVw)

        let vwY = (self.otherVidY+scrollH-10)-30
        let view: UIView = UIView.init(frame: CGRectMake(5, vwY, imgvwWidth, 30))
        view.backgroundColor=UIColor.blackColor()
        self.scroll.addSubview(view)

        if let imgURL = NSURL(string: urlString)
        {
            do {
                if let img = imageCache[urlString] {
                    imgVw.image = img
                }

                else
                {
                    // The image isn't cached, download the img data
                    // We should perform this in a background thread
                    let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL)
                    let mainQueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
                    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: mainQueue, completionHandler: { (response, data, error) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {
                            // Convert the downloaded data in to a UIImage object
                            let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                            let resizedImage = self.resizeImage(image!, newWidth: imgVw.frame.size.width, imageView: imgVw)
                            // Store the image in to our cache
                            self.imageCache[urlString] = resizedImage
                            // Update the cell
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                                imgVw.image = resizedImage
                                var rect = imgVw.frame
                                rect.size.height = resizedImage.size.height
                                imgVw.frame = rect
                                self.otherVidY = imgVw.frame.origin.y+imgVw.frame.size.height+5

                            })
                        }
                        else {
                            print("Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                        }
                    })
                }

            }

        }

        self .otherVidY=imgVw.frame.size.height+imgVw.frame.origin.y+5
        self.scroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(self.screenWidth, self.otherVidY+imgVw.frame.size.height)



    }
```

but I am facing a problem when I set the Y value of the next image. Its, overlapping. How to solve this issue. Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here, You have to deal with origins and that only depends on your logic. You can use.

```
object(View).frame.size.origin
```

it will give you the X, Y of view and

`view.frame.size.height` & `view.frame.size.width`

It will give you the height and weight.

Then you need to set CGRect for your ImageView That you want .